# Prevent downloading of geojson files with specific media query

Tags: css, vue.js

I use a vue.js app to select locations with either a map or an input field. But I'd like to serve just the search engine and no map for mobile users.

Problem: it's not very usable on mobile because while I prevented map display with a media query, I can't find a way to avoid the downloading of a fairly big geojson and a bunch of related data files.

The imports go like this:

```
//modules for leaflet
import Vue2Leaflet from '../../node_modules/vue2-leaflet/dist/vue2-leaflet.js'; 
import { InfoControl, ReferenceChart, ChoroplethLayer } from 'vue-choropleth'
//geojson and data files
import { geojsonA } from '../../data/mygeojson.min.geojson' 
import { specificData } from '../../data/mydata.js'
```

and in the styles:

```
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  //other styles
}
```

Is there a way to selectively prevent import with media queries or any other method for specific displays?

Comment: Move it in a component and include this component (`v-if`) only on a certain window width. You need to read those values in JavaScript though.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Thanks. I'm not sure to see exactly what you mean by reading those values in Javascript. Would you mind give me some more details or directions?

Comment: If you wanna prevent the import itself then there are also solutions if you are looking for that?

Comment: In JavaScript, you need to define the same properties as in the media query. That means in your case, that you need to read the width of the screen within JavaScript. You can read this value from the `window` object. Then the constant  `640px` need also to be defined in JavaScript too.

Comment: @badgy yes that's exactly what I'm looking for! So I could compare with the media query solution and see which one would be better

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you need to define the media query in JavaScript too, to make conditions based on e.g. the width of the window. Because these values are not reactive, and can therefore not easily be watched with Vue, you need to define your own watcher.

Here is an example. The `<test/>` element is only added, if the screen is wide enough. If the screen is not wide enough, it is not loaded (`v-if` removes it completely). On `mounted`, there is an event listener added to the `resize` event of the window. So, everytime you resize your window, the value is updated. This value can then be used in the computed property `largeScreen`. This returns a boolean, if the screen is large or not. This boolean is then used in the template. The `<test/>` component would then import your script.

Make sure to clean up custom event listeners `beforeDestroy`, otherwise, they might be defined multiple times.

```js
Vue.component('test', {
  template: '<div>Large screen; <code>test</code> is loaded.</div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      windowWidth: 0
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setWindowWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.setWindowWidth);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setWindowWidth);
  },
  computed: {
    largeScreen: function() {
      return this.windowWidth > 640;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setWindowWidth: function() {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Screen width is: <code>{{ windowWidth }}px</code>

  <test v-if="largeScreen" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matchMedia` to create media query breakpoints within JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

It has really good support and might be even easier to set up than using a resize listener and less resource intensive.